# How to import a c++ project into QT creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I have created a project in QT creator, in VisualStudio I created a c++ project which sends an email to a user. Now I want to import this project into the Qt creator and make use of this functionality in my Qt creator project. The c++ folder contains a couple of .cpp files,header files and a make file. I am not sure how to import this project into QT creator and make it run. I tried to look for a solution but could not find it.Could you let me know how it can be done?

Comment: We don't know enough of type of VS project you have. There is an easy conversion from Qt project to VS project but maybe not the other way around. I would start with an empty Qt project in Creator and routinely add all the source code files and libraries. This exercise takes understanding and certainly cannot be done without sufficient information. That can be graded a project on its own, meaning quite a work if we import significant project.

Answer (score 6):

> File > New file or project... > Import Project > Import Existing
>   Project